# Working of fork() system call

Tags: c, fork

This is my Code -->>

```
#include  <stdio.h> 
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/wait.h>
#include  <unistd.h>


int main()
{
int i ;
int x = 10 ;
int pid1, pid2, status ;

printf("Before forking, the value of x is %d\n", x);

/*
   After forking, we make the parent and its two children
       increment x in different ways to illustrate that they
   have different copies of x
*/


if ((pid1 = fork()) == 0) {

    /* First child process */
    for (i=0 ; i < 5; i++) {
       printf("\t\t\t At first child: x= %d\n", x);
       x= x+10;
       sleep(2) ; /* Sleep for 1 second */
    }
}
else {

    /* Parent process */

    /* Create another child process */
    if ((pid2 = fork()) == 0) {

        /* Second child process */
                for (i=0 ; i < 5; i++) {
                printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t At second child: x= %d\n", x);
                x= x+20;
        sleep(2) ; /* Sleep for 1 second */
                }
    }
    else {

        /* Parent process */
        for (i=0 ; i < 5; i++) {
            printf("At parent: x= %d\n", x);
            x= x+5;
            sleep(1) ; /* Sleep for 1 second */
        }

        /*
            The waitpid() system call causes the parent
            to wait for a child process with a specific pid to complete
            its execution. The input parameter can
            specify the PID of the child process for
            which it has to wait.
        */

        waitpid(pid1, &status, 0);
        waitpid(pid2, &status, 0);
    }
}
}
```

The output of this is like --->

Before forking, the value of x is 10

At second child: x= 10

At second child: x= 30

At second child: x= 50

At second child: x= 70

At second child: x= 90

Before forking, the value of x is 10

At first child: x= 10

At first child: x= 20

At first child: x= 30

At first child: x= 40

At first child: x= 50

Before forking, the value of x is 10

At parent: x= 10

At parent: x= 15

At parent: x= 20

At parent: x= 25

At parent: x= 30

Why is the printf statement , "Before forking , the value of x is 10" getting printed thrice when it's above all the fork() system calls. ?? Please help.

Comment: I ran this code. It only printed the "Before forking" line once.

Comment: (after replacing calls to `Sleep` with `sleep` and removing the `* 1000`, at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `fflush(stdout)` before each `fork()`.

Comment: I wonder why `stdout` wasn't flushed nevertheless - at least, the string in question ends with a `\n`...